# Survey123 submit survey as geopoint, geotrace, or geoshape

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-survey123

I would like to create a single survey that can submit the survey response as a point, a line, or a polygon.

The survey user will be prompted whether they would like to collect a point, line, or polygon and the correct geopoint, geotrace, or geoshape question will appear depending on the choice. That is easy enough, but what I can't find a solution to is how to force Survey123 to submit the survey to a different feature layer depending on which geometry type is selected.

Is this possible? In theory it should be. It would be collecting a single geometry type per submission, but would need to submit to a different feature layer depending on the selected geometry type.

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up three repeats, each of which is only 'relevant' (visible) if the appropriate GeoXXX option is chosen

One repeat with a geopoint question, one with a geotrace question and one with a geoshape question.

In each of these repeats, set the number of repeats to 1 (unless you do want more than one geoXXX item per survey).

Optionally, other survey questions could be in the repeats, but that would triple the work for each of those questions. Best to keep other questions out of the repeats unless absolutely necessary.